# What needs to happen for a link inside a Kendo grid to open a file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid in an MVC project where one column is a link to a file.  When the user clicks on the link, I'd like the file to open in a new tab or at least download.  Instead when clicking on the link, nothing happens.  The file path is correct; if I copy and paste it in a browser window it will open the file.  My thought is that something in the Kendo grid is blocking the link.  Can anyone tell me how to get the link to open the file?

Here's the relevant column from the grid:

```
    columns.Bound(m => m.CoDocsName).Title("Name")
     .ClientTemplate(
         "<a href='#= CoDocsPath#'>#= CoDocsName #</a>"
     );
```

The link resolves to "file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Attachments/files.txt".  If you hover over the link in the grid, you can see this path.  If you copy and past this into a browser window, it will show the file.  Clicking on the link inside the grid does nothing.

Comment: Please provide virtual path or web path. like http://yourdomain/yourfolder/filename

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I changed the value of CoDocsPath until the link resolved to http://localhost:53091/Attachments/files.txt and it worked.  Haven't tried this yet on a server though.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working on MVC, I would suggest, invoking an action method to download the file from server instead of using HREF. This will need the below steps:

1. Call Download action method from your controller with the file name.
2. Determine the full path to fetch the file from and determine its MIME type download the file in the correct format.
3. Finally use ContentDisposition appended to the response header to initiate a the download.

Here is the readily consumable client side and server side code for you to use:

**Client Side template to invoke server call:**

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).Width("6%")
            .Title("Download")
            .ClientTemplate("<a href='" +
            Url.Action("Download", "Attachment", new { fileName= "#=FileName#" }) +
            "'><i class='icon-download'></i></a> ");
```

**Server Side Action method:**

```
public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName != null)
        {
            string path = @""; //eg "C:\\Attachment"                
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fullPath);
            var fileBytes = SysFile.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);

            // Convert to ContentDisposition
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                Inline = false,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

            // View document
            return File(fileBytes, contentType);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Please let me know how did it work for you.